# Selected options should display in text area from a multiple select dropdown

Tags: spring, jsp

I have a dropdown which can select multiple options. I want to display selected options like a string in a text area. But I am getting only 1st value selected. I am using JSP and Javascript for this.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sp" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkEmp(value)
{
 var eName = document.getElementById("empyee");
 var prev = '';
 if(value != "")
 {
  
  alert(prev);
  prev = prev+ value;
  alert(value);
  alert(prev);
  eName.value = value;
 }
}
</script>
<body>
<select  name="individual" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="dd5" size="6" onchange='checkEmp(this.value);'>
  <option value=""></option>
   <c:forEach var="emp" items="${emp}">
        <option value="${emp.employee_Name}">${emp.employee_Name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
  </select>
  <textarea id="empyee" name="empyee" ></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set 'prev' as below which will be having updated value.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sp" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkEmp(value)
{
 var eName = document.getElementById("empyee");
 var prev = '';
 if(value != "")
 {
  
  alert(prev);
  prev = prev+ value;
  alert(value);
  alert(prev);
  eName.value = prev;
 }
}
</script>
<body>
<select  name="individual" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="dd5" size="6" onchange='checkEmp(this.value);'>
  <option value=""></option>
   <c:forEach var="emp" items="${emp}">
        <option value="${emp.employee_Name}">${emp.employee_Name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
  </select>
  <textarea id="empyee" name="empyee" ></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No .Still I am not getting string with previous value.

Comment: var prev = ''; should be outside of the function checkEmp(value) . Sothat every time it will not cleared.

Comment: yeah.Now values are appending, but if I select an option below to the previous option,it is appending previous value itself